# Não consigo criar array dinamico com Session

Tags: php

Minha aplicação é o seguinte, são digitadas palavras em um formulário, e o programa identifica a quantidade caracteres que ela possui, se essa quantidade for IMPAR, ele adiciona a palavra em uma tabela

veja como funciona, no caso a palavra digitada foi jao.

[image: Imagem da aplicação]

ai se eu for adicionar outra palavra impar, ele cria a tabela apenas com a palavra atual.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

queria saber como faço para ele ir adicionando na tabela toda palavra impar, sem criar um nova tabela apenas com a palavra atual digitada.

segue o código:

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['var'] = array();
  $_SESSION['tam'] = array();

  function postImpar($nome){

  if((strlen($nome) % 2)!= 0){
    
    array_push($_SESSION['var'], $nome);
    array_push($_SESSION['tam'], strlen($nome));

    }
  }

  echo'<form action="calcula.php" method="post">

    <br />Nome:<input type="text" name="nome" /><br /><br />
       <input type="submit" />

  </form>';


        echo "<h1>Ímpares</h1>";

        echo'<table border="1">';
        if (isset($_POST["nome"])) {

          postImpar($_POST["nome"]);

          $x = $_SESSION['var'];
          $y = $_SESSION['tam'];

          $tam = count($x);

          for($i = 0; $i < $tam; $i++){
            echo "<tr>"."<td>$x[$i]</td>".
            "<td>$y[$i]</td>".
            "</tr>";

        }

    }

      echo"</table>";


 ?>
```

Comment: Toda vez que vc envia um subit está resetando o valor do `$_SESSION`, remova ou comente essas suas linhas `$_SESSION['var'] = array();
  $_SESSION['tam'] = array();`

Comment: Vlw, pela ajuda era isso mesmo, não sabia que tava resetando

Agradeço, deus lhe pague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No inicio do seu código, está sendo criado um array vazio. Logo, sempre que o código é iniciado o array é "resetado".

Basta no inicio declarar da seguinte maneira:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['var'])){
    $_SESSION['var'] = array();
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['tam'])){
    $_SESSION['tam'] = array();
}
```

Comment: É verdade, era isso mesmo o erro, muito obrigado primo

Agradeço, deus lhe pague.

Comment: De nada, disponha. Só marcas como resolvido, Abs.